# Getting Skybox to change on collision in unity with UnityScript?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm quite new to UnityScript as my area of interest is python, however me and a friend are planning to create a small indie game and I need the skybox to change on collision in unity. I would prefer this to be done in javascript if at all possible. Please take a look at it and let me know whats wrong with it, as when run it makes no difference to the scene.

```
#pragma strict    
var mat:Material;
function OnTriggerEnter(trigger: Collider){
    RenderSettings.skybox=mat;

}
```

That is the entire script. Thank you for any help given

Comment: have you tried Debug.Log("Message") to ensure the OnTriggerEnter function is executed?

Comment: Ok so nothing came up when I tried replacing RenderSettings.skybox=mat; with Debug.Log("Message"; so taking a friends advice I did this 'code' 
}


function collisionCall(){
if (Collision == true){
Debug.Log("Its true");
}
}
'code' and still nothing is logged. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: try CthulhuJon's answer. ALso did you mark the collider as Trigger? If not, you need to use the OnCollisionEnter instead of OnTriggerEnter Function http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html

Answer (score 1):

make sure that for your objects that collide... typically one must have a static collider (e.g. floor, wall) and the other a collider and rigidBody to hit it (e.g. player, car). Also check your physics settings to make sure the layers that the objects are in, can hit each other.
Make sure you have your script on the right object... collider or collidee ?  try putting a script on both objects with a print in each.
Check here for more info
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Physics.html

Answer (score 1):

What exactly to you mean by changing on collision? Skyboxes cannot be collided with. If you mean objects colliding other than the skybox, make sure that at least one of the collider's has "Is Trigger" checked in the inspector.